# Is there a way to test for nil with ==

Tags: swift

I would like to test an optional variable for nil as part of a compound test and am getting a surprising result.  I'm hoping someone can set me straight on how my thought process is off.

The code in question is part of a function within a class named GameBoard:

```
if depth == 9, winner == nil {
  tied = true
}
```

The optional variable winner and boolean variable tied are defined at the top of the class definition as:

```
private(set) var winner : Player?
private(set) var tied   : Bool = false
```

To help get a better understanding I rewrote the test as follows an watched it under the debugger:

```
if depth == 9 {
  if winner == nil {  // set breakpoint here
    tied = true       // never get here, even when depth is 9 and winner is nil
  }
}
```

Yes, I could rewrite this to use "!= nil"...

```
if depth == 9 {
  if winner != nil {} // set breakpoint here
  else {  
    tied = true       // never get here, even when depth is 9 and winner is nil
  }
}
```

...but the logic behind the code becomes less readable.

My question is twofold.  Is there something inherently wrong with using == to test for nil?  Is there a cleaner solution than doing a negative test and putting desired logic in the else block?

Thanks much

I added a screenshot of the debugger session to show that I'm not completely nuts here.  The execution stopped at the breakpoint on line 101.  I then took one additional (code) step to bring the execution flow to line 104.  This is where I took the snapshot.  As you can see, self.winner has a value of nil and self.tied has a value of false.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `== nil` works fine. Can you show a minimal, complete example that shows the issue? I suspect the values are not what you think they are.

Comment: Have tried removing your breakpoint ?

Comment: @Rob, I added a screenshot of the debugger session.  I'll see if I can find another simple example.

Comment: @Leo, Yes/no.  I was seeing the same behavior without the breakpoint.  I added the breakpoint to help me hone in on where the logic flow problem was originating.   I don't want to completely remove the breakpoint as it would be mind-numbing to try to catch the exact condition without it.  Nonetheless, I tried removing the breakpoint AFTER hitting it with the self.winner == nil condition.  Same result.

Comment: The most common cause of this kind of behavior is debugger artifacts (particularly if optimizations are turned on). The next most common cause is multi-threading (accessing these variables through multiple threads). The next most common (but very, very uncommon) is non-threading memory corruption (particularly unusual in pure Swift). In any of these cases I recommend simplifying the problem; keep taking things out until the problem goes away. Comment out more and more of the program if you have to (or pull small pieces into another program). But `==` does work, so that's not the cause.

Comment: @Rob, If you make this an answer rather than a comment, I will flag it as the accepted answer.   My question was whether or not it was inherently wrong to use == to test for nil.  You provided the answer to that question.  Armed with that knowledge, I will continue to pursue the underlying issue (which I suspect may be in GameplayKit (or my use of it) as I am getting other strange results out of it.  Thanks much

Comment: (1) "This is where I took the snapshot. As you can see, self.winner has a value of nil and self.tied has a value of false." That proves nothing about `self.tied`, since we have not reached that line yet so we haven't had a chance to set it to true. Values for lines you have not come to yet are meaningless.

Comment: (2) There is a bug in LLDB where things are shown as nil when they are not. I do not know whether this bug extends to GKGameModelPlayer objects.

Comment: I definitely agree with matt that if the only evidence you have is the debugger, then there's no actual issue here. The debugger lies all the time.

Comment: Except that the reason that I went to debugger was because of an unexpected behavior.  What the debugger showed was entirely consistent with the unexpected behavior.  In addition, print statements were revealing the same.   Based on your response that that there is nothing wrong with testing for nil using ==, then I can only surmise that that there is a deeper issue.  I am fairly new to Swift, but have nearly 3 decades of coding experience under my belt—gut tells me this is a linking or other memory issue.  This is backed by other issues I am seeing that could be explained by memory corruption

Comment: @RobNapier.  Thank you for taking the time to go through this with me.  I do appreciate it.  As this is throw away code, I don't expect that I'm going to do too much more digging into the root cause as I have a workaround that works.   BUT... if I see this behavior again in other code, I will definitely invest the time to get to its root.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common cause of this kind of behavior is debugger artifacts (particularly if optimizations are turned on). The next most common cause is multi-threading (accessing these variables through multiple threads). The next most common (but very, very uncommon) is non-threading memory corruption (particularly unusual in pure Swift). In any of these cases I recommend simplifying the problem; keep taking things out until the problem goes away. Comment out more and more of the program if you have to (or pull small pieces into another program). But `==` does work for nil, so that's not the cause.

Comment: But he's claiming (in a comment on my answer) that if his code reads `if winner == nil { print("nil") }; if winner != nil { print("not nil") }` nothing prints! That's not the debugger and I doubt it's multithreading.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Swift bug in LLDB where things are shown as `nil` when they are not. It applies mostly to Foundation overlay objects but perhaps it also applies here. The only workaround is to `print` instead. I would suggest running this code:

```
if depth == 9 {
  print("depth is", depth)
  print("winner is", winner)
  if winner == nil {
    tied = true
  }
}
```

I'm going to guess that `winner` will turn out *not* to be `nil`.

Comment: I did something similar, I added two conditional print statements:

`
    if winner == nil { print("nil") }
    if winner != nil { print("not nil") }
    if winner != nil { } else { print("else not nil" }
`

The only output was "else not nil"

Comment: I'm just having trouble accepting the claim that if you run code that reads `if winner == nil { print("nil") }; if winner != nil { print("not nil") }` neither `print` statement prints. That would be just nuts. I've never seen or heard of anything like it. You'd have to show me. Can you? For example, maybe post a github project that demonstrates...?

Comment: I haven't kept myself held up by this weird behavior.  Not sure how hard it will be to get back to the state where I can demo it again.   I'll take a stab at it tonight... and if I can recreate the code/result, I'll post to github.

Answer (score 0):

using the && (and) operators, but make sure the scope is correct for var 'tied'

```swift
if depth == 9 && winner == nil {
  tied = true
}
```

Comment: I tried using both a comma and "&&" in this expression and got the same behavior either way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way here is to turn `tied` into a computed property

```
var tied : Bool {
    winner == nil && depth == 9
}
```

this assumes `depth` is a property but if it is a variable inside the function I would write it like

```
tied = winner == nil && depth == 9
```

Off-topic, rather than just using 9 in your code it might be better to define a constant property and use it instead

Comment: I had tried exactly what you suggested... Same result.
I also tried changing depth from being a stored variable to a computed property.  Again, same result.

Comment: Typically, I try to avoid hardcoded constant values, but this project was supposed to be (and still is) throw-away code that I'm using to get a better handle on the use of GameplayKit.  As a tic-tac-toe board always has exactly 9 grid cells, I went ahead and just used that value here.   But, in general, I concur with your recommendation.

Comment: @MikeMayer67 I think I answered the question in the title more than the question in the text.